# Change size of div when showing error message

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not able to change the height of the div when showing the error messages after submitting the form so that there is no overflow. I can set the height property to `1100px` so that there is no overflow anymore but it looks quite ugly having so much white space.

I created a JSFiddle because it is a lot of code and since most of the code is relevant for the problem it is quite difficult to reduce it.

```
     <div class="contact-form-wrap">
        <div class="contact-form-wrap-left">
          <div class="col full-width"><ul class="error-message"></ul></div>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-form-wrap-right ">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried to set the height to auto with a `min-height` of `760px`. The div still does not grow. I changed the display property of contact-form-wrap-left to display: inline-block but since float is used this seems not to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/ArisMartinAccola/ud8x5e9o/

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: So, are you asking for help changing the height of the div tag? Do you want it to happen depending on the height of the error message or a fixed height?

Comment: @GuybrushThreepwood My idea is that the height of the div changes dynamically so that the <div class="contact-form-wrap-left"> fits in perfectly without having extra white space around.

Comment: Are you forced to using pure CSS or can you use a framework like Bootstrap?

Comment: @GuybrushThreepwood CSS is preferred.

Comment: I think the problem is that you use too many fixed heights in your css for div elements that contain other elements.

Comment: @Zarec And what you suggest to change?

Answer (score 0):

Change place of divs like this

```
<div class="col full-width"><ul class="error-message"></ul></div>

            <form action="config.php" method="post" class="contact-form">
```

After that set col full-width with position relative and contact-form to relative as well. Of course, use create ID's for both of those